# Eliminar botón columnas Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

tras varios días manipulando tablas con Bootstrap me he encotnrado un problema a la hora de quitar un botón que viene por defecto. En la imagen de abajo se ve  (Está rodeada por un círculo).
[image: Img1]
¿Alguna solución?

El código de crear la tabla es el siguiente (se crea mediante la librería Bootstrap):

```
var params = {
    intCodInversor: lender_id
};

var funcion = 'ObtenerPujasPorInversorNoTraspasadasIncluyendoEnTramites';

$.post('full_calls.php', {params: params, 'function': funcion}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (refresh == false)
        CrearTablaData($table, data, null, null, 25);

    if (refresh == true) {
        $table.bootstrapTable("load", data);
    }


}, "json");
```

Y la función CrearTableData llamada simplemente a la función que dejo a continuación:

```
    function CrearTablaDataSearch(tabla, data, _onPostBody, toolbar, pages, search, search_align, filtro)
{
    if(search_align==null)
        search_align = 'left';

    if(toolbar==null)
        toolbar=".toolbar";

    if(toolbar==undefined)
        toolbar=".toolbar";

    if(_onPostBody==null)
        _onPostBody=undefined;

    if(pages==null||pages==undefined)
        pages=5;

    if(filtro==null)
        filtro = true;

    tabla.bootstrapTable({
        toolbar: toolbar,
        clickToSelect: true,
        showRefresh: false,
        search: search,
        showToggle: false,
        showColumns: filtro,
        pagination: true,
        searchAlign: search_align,
        pageSize: pages,
        clickToSelect: false,
        pageList: [5,10,25,50,100,500],
        data: data, 
        formatShowingRows: function(pageFrom, pageTo, totalRows){
            //do nothing here, we don't want to show the text "showing x of y from..."
        },
        formatRecordsPerPage: function(pageNumber){
            return pageNumber + " filas visibles";
        },
        formatNoMatches: function() {
            return "No hay registros";
        },
        formatLoadingMessage: function(){
            return "Cargando...";
        },
        formatSearch: function(){
            return "Buscar";
        },
        icons: {
            refresh: 'fa fa-refresh',
            toggle: 'fa fa-th-list',
            columns: 'fa fa-columns',
            detailOpen: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
            detailClose: 'fa fa-minus-circle',
            paginationSwitchDown:'fa fa-plus-circle',
            paginationSwitchUp:'fa fa-minus-circle'
        },
        onPostBody: _onPostBody
    });

    //activate the tooltips after the data table is initialized
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        tabla.bootstrapTable('resetView');
    });

}
```

El código que tengo en el html para mostrar la tabla es el siguiente:

```
                                    <div id="toolbar2" class="toolbar">

                                </div>

                                <table id="tabla_inversiones" class="table p-10" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-row-style="formatearFilaInversiones">
                                    <thead>
                                         <th width="5%" data-field="PRE_CD_PRESTAMO" data-sortable="false" class="text-center" data-formatter="formatearPlanDetalleYPlanConCodigo">INFO<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pulse sobre el icono de informaci&oacute;n para ver el detalle del proyecto / promotor"></i></sup></th>

                                         <th width="5%" data-field="TIN_OBJ" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="formatearAPorcentajeEnTablaGrande" class="text-center">TIPO INTERES<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tipo de inter&eacute;s para el inversor"></i></sup></th>
                                         <th width="5%" data-field="RATING" data-sortable="false" class="text-center" data-formatter="formatearRating">RATING<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Rating asignado al pr&eacute;stamo"></i></sup></th>
                                         <th width="10%" data-field="PROYECTO" data-sortable="false" data-formatter="formatearPrestamo">PR&Eacute;STAMO<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Nombre del pr&eacute;stamo"></i></sup></th>
                                         <th width="10%" data-field="IMPORTE_Y_PLAZOS" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="importePrestamoYPendiente" class="text-center">IMPORTE<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Importe total a financiar y meses que dura la financiaci&oacute;n"></i></sup></th>

                                         <th width="15%" data-field="CAPITAL_ESPERADO" data-sortable="false" class="text-center width-180" data-formatter="formatearInversion" >INVERSION<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Importe total invertido en el pr&eacute;stamo"></i></sup></th>
                                         <th width="15%" data-field="INTERESES_ESPERADOS" data-sortable="false" class="text-center width-200" data-formatter="formatearInteresesEsperados">INT. ESPERADOS<sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Importe de intereses que se espera recibir por las inversiones realizadas en el pr&eacute;stamo"></i></sup></th>

                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody> 
                                    </tbody>
                                    <tfoot id="tfoot_foot">
                                        <th id="thInfo" class="text-center"><b>TOTAL</b><sup>&nbsp;<i class="icon_info fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-tooltip="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="Esta fila es la de totales, la informaci&oacute;n que se muestra son totales ponderados por la inversi&oacute;n realizada en cada uno de los casos, excepto lo que son sumatorios, que únicamente se realiza la suma de todas las inversiones."></i></sup></th>

                                        <th id="thTipoMedio" class="text-center"></th>
                                        <th id="thRating" class="text-center"></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th id="thPlazos" class="text-center"></th>
                                        <th id="thInversion" class="text-center"></th>
                                        <th id="thIntereses" class="text-center"></th>

                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Hola Sergio. Puedes añadir el código html y tus intentos para quitar el botón?. ¿Que problema exacto tienes? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b os he añadido tanto el código de HTML como el de JS. La creación de tablas se hace mediante la librería Bootstrap.

Comment: @blonfu te he añadido el codigo.

Comment: te quito el negativo

Comment: @blonfu y que es lo que pone en el título de [en espera]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu javascript dentro de la función **CrearTablaDataSearch** cambia

```
showColumns: filtro,
```

Por:

```
showColumns: false,
```